# Call R function from C wrapper

Tags: r

I have a function like so:

```
callFunc <- function (f) {
    f(1)
}
```

`f` could be (for example) `f <- function (x) x`. To simplify things, let's say that I know that f should return a numeric and take in a single numeric.

I'd like to move `callFunc` to C, but still have the function `f` defined in R, i.e.

```
.Call('callFunc', function (x) x)
```

I'm struggling with how to evaluate my callback on the C side.
I have it like this at the moment:

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rdefines.h>

SEXP callFunc (SEXP i_func) {
    return i_func(1);
}
```

(Then to test it:

```
R CMD SHLIB test.c
# then in R
dyn.load('test.so'); .Call('callFunc', function (x) x)
```

)

Of course, the above does not work because

- I have not coerced `i_func` into the appropriate closure form; I'm not sure how to do this (there are `AS_foo` macros in `Rdefines.h`, but no `AS_CLOSURE`).
- I haven't even told the C code that `i_func` should take in a numeric and return a numeric, so how can it even evaluate?

Could anyone give me pointers on how to go about doing this?
I'm working my way through [writing R extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html) but this is rather long and I haven't found what I'm after yet. Also there is [this question on R-help](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2011-September/062052.html) but the answer looks like they implemented the callback `f` in C as well, rather than leaving it as an R object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very easy with Rcpp:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction("SEXP callFun(Function f) {
  return f(1);
}")

callFun(function(x) x + 10)
# [1] 11
```

Comment: cheers! Do you know how it would be done without Rcpp, for completeness? (avoiding adding extra dependencies for example)

Comment: No, and I have spent long enough reading the disaster of r internals documentation that I have no intention of finding out ;)

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, here is how you'd do it without Rcpp (I took my cue from the XML package, which lets you provide handlers). You construct a call (first argument is the function as a SEXP, subsequent arguments are the function arguments, all SEXP) and use `eval`.

```
// takes a callback and evaluates it (with argument 1), returning the result.   
SEXP callFunc(SEXP func) {                                      
    SEXP call, ans;                                              

    PROTECT(call = allocVector(LANGSXP, 2)); // call + arg       

    SEXP c;                                                      
    c = call;                                                    

    SETCAR(call, func);                                          
    c = CDR(c);                                                  

    // for some reason if I just SETCDR(c, ScalarReal(1.0)) I get
    // a memory fault, but using SETCAR like this is fine. 
    SETCAR(c, ScalarReal(1.0));                      

    ans = eval(call, R_GlobalEnv);  // maybe PROTECT?
    UNPROTECT(1);             

    return(ans);              
}
```

From R:

```
.Call('callFunc', function (x) sin(x))
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you are missing a couple of `PROTECTS/UNPROTECTS`. My understanding is that every declaration of `SEXP` should be accompanied by `PROTECT/UNPROTECT`. Thanks for adding this!